# How to draw MACD and EMA in one script ( Pine Editor)-Tradingview

Tags: finance, pine-script

I want to draw MACD and EMA in one script . i implement like below :

```
//@version=3
study("Example of alertcondition")
fast = 12, slow = 26
fastMA = ema(close, fast)
slowMA = ema(close, slow)
macd = fastMA - slowMA
src = input(close)
ma_2 = ema(src, 36)
plot(ma_2, color=red)
plot(macd, color=blue)
```

But it don't draw anything. If i remove

```
plot(ma_2, color=red)
```

so script will draw MACD.if i  remove

```
plot(macd, color=blue)
```

so script draw EMA. Why can not draw two indicators in this case ?

Can anyone help me .

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it does draw both, but the scale of the two indicators are way off. You need to normalize them to be able to see them on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok.
 But your two values can be really different so that you can't see both on screen